# Index creation takes too much time in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

With the following cluster:

- 3 master nodes
- 4 data nodes
- 2 client nodes

We store time series. We have ~100 alias (each one correspond to a certain type of document) under which we have ~2500 indices. An index is a time partition which corresponds to a week of data. So, `_cat/aliases` gives something like:

```
alias  index
foo    foo_201844
foo    foo_201845
bar    bar_201844
bar    bar_201845
```

As time goes by, new partitions are added as well as new aliases. Indice sizes may vary a lot from one week to another and from one alias to another. This time-based partitioning was motivated by three reasons:

- This sounded healthy
- This is what's done in the basic example with logstash
- This helps us doing some structure manipulation like field deletion while keeping real-time ingestion

We observed that indice creation time increases a lot and sometimes is in timeout (which is set to 30s).

I could increase the timeout but it feels like procrastinating. Is Elasticsearch designed to handle that many indices? Should i change this partition strategy? Is it just a problem of resources?

Comment: I think is just a problem of workers, did you tried to use logstash to index your data and how many cpu do you have ?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't use logstash, and i have 4 cpus on master & data nodes, and 8 cpus on client nodes

Comment: if you have a lot of data, you should increase the number of workers (cpu), for your case you have 4 CPUs is not enough and can you do a `top` and `shift+1` on your terminal to show how many CPU works when you index your data.

Comment: It seems there's a misunderstanding here, i'm not talking about indexing but just index creation (eg https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html)